# App hangs in ios5 when accessing twitter account

Tags: ios

I am working on an app which access twitter account. I am getting the access to twitter using following function

```
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeTwitter
                             withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
```

above function is getting called from app delegate's "applicationDidBecomeActive" function.

This works fine in iOS 6. But in iOS 5, it shows alert as usual asking permission to access the account. When i press "ok" or "don't allow",  applicationDidBecomeActive function getting called again. So it acts like a loop and alert keep coming.

Am i doing anything wrong other than calling it from applicationDidBecomeActive ?

Comment: looks like ios6 save user permission and never ask user again. but in ios 5 user permission is not being saved

Answer (score 1):

Try to dispatch the completion handler on the main thread. I've got an "issue" on iOS5 where I wanted to display an alert view after login into TW account. On iOS6 everything was fine but on iOS5 it seemed to show the alert view after 5 sec. I've fixed dispatching the alert on main thread.
If in the completion handler you have some UI functionalities, dispatch them on the main thread, because UIKit for the majority isn't thread safe.
 Ciao

Answer (score 0):

```
requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:
```

method is available only in iOS6 and above.

For iOS5 Use:

```
requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler:
```

**EDIT::**

```
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                  withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (granted) 
             {
                 //MY CODE
             }
            else{
             // do whatever you want to do when user dont allow the access to the app
             }
         });
     }];
```

Comment: Iam using requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler: only for ios 5. tap ok will work fine. but if i tap on "dont allow", alert will come again when i call the function next time. But in iOS 6. it just fail with out any user alert. any clue?

Comment: Yeah, iam doing the same. My problem is the popup 'app would like to access your twitter account' is showing as soon as i call the funcion.this is happening only when i say 'don't allow'(in iOS 5)

Comment: When you say Dont allow, the granted variable will be NO. Use an else block to do whatever you want to do when user dont allow the access to account.

Comment: understand. but my problem is showing pop up again and again after user denied access (on app launch). iOS 6 wont ask user permission again once i say "don't allow".

Comment: Ok. Now I got it. In iOS5 it may not be able to save the permission. i am not able to find that in documentation though. You can save it manually anytime. In else block, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];

And then at the start of the function:
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"]) {
    // call function
}

Comment: ohh ok.. but how i know when user changes permission in settings?

Comment: if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]), if the user has one twitter account configured then this method returns YES. see if you can use this method in your app to solve the problem.